# Parallel async calls without custom await function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I want to run a loop parallelly using an async function. So I tried :

```js
let counters = [0,0]


const calc = async(x) => {
  for(let i=0; i<10; i+=1) {
    counters[x]+=1;
    console.log(counters[0], counters[1]);
  }
}

calc(0)
calc(1)
```

After this try, I found that the async function calls actually release for the next function call before termination if await inside the function.

So, I modified the function and it works :

```js
let counters = [0,0]

const delay = () => new Promise(resolve=>resolve())


const calc = async(x) => {
  for(let i=0; i<10; i+=1){
    await delay()
    counters[x]+=1;
    console.log(counters[0],counters[1]);
  }
}

calc(0)
calc(1)
```

But, this delay is not aligned with the logic of the loop. So, is there a way to run loops para rally without it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve here, what would the real implementation of delay look like? What is your expected result? Async/await is just sugar over syntax, so I'm unsure if this will solve your problem or not, however, I'm not exactly sure what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: If you aren't using await why would you need `async` in the first place? Are you actually performing asynchronous operations in these loops? Defintely some details missing here

Comment: the real implementation of loop changes, but the delay is the same. delay is just used to run two loops pararally. Currently, I am looking for a way to do without it.

Comment: My objective is to run multiple for-loops pararal

Comment: Since javascript is single threaded the only way you could get real parallel is by using webWorkers to run one and main engine the other

Comment: @NilankaManoj notice that in your second example they are still in order no matter how many times you run it.  It's not "real parallel".

Comment: Isn't there to make it real pararal?

Comment: If that is your goal, then (realistically or pragmatically) no.  Short of doing web workers like charlietfl mentioned.  I guess you could use something like this wrapper for web workers: https://parallel.js.org/ which will make it easier to achieve what you are asking for.  But chances are most probably it isn't what you need and there's a better solution, and that the answer traktor53 gave covers what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

`async` functions and `await` allow you to write asynchronous code as if were sequential. Meaning the code is forced to perform asynchronous operations one after another by having `await` return to the event loop until the settled fate of its operand promise becomes known.

The whole point of `await` is to code obtaining data results in sequential steps which is the opposite of parallel processing - and you can't launch two `await` operations in parallel in the same `async` function.

If you want parallel operation of asynchronous processes, create an array of promises, one for each individual operation result (e.g. by using the promise returned from calling an async function which performs a single operation) and using one of the static Promise methods, such as `all`, `race` or `settled` to deal with results obtained in parallel.

Comment: The OP is noticing that asynchronous !== multi-threaded, and that the call stack still resolves in order.  What he's also noticing, is that await causes injecting of the intermediate yielded positions into an intermediate call stack, so it looks as if they are resolving concurrently.  What you're currently outlining here doesn't really answer or address his question.

Comment: @user120242 I suspect the post is an XY question - the title is asking about parallel calls after trying unsuccessfully to use `await` for a problem later  described as "running multiple loop in parallel". If the OP decides to edit the question with what the problem actually is I would happily reconsider the relevance of  this answer.